# Class member function declared outside of public, protected and private

Tags: c++, class, member

I came across some code that looked like this:

```
class SomeClass {
   void SomeFunction();

public:
   ~~ public members
}
```

There were no private or protected members of the class.

My question is; is not labelling what part of the class the 'SomeFunction' belongs to bad programming? Or does defining the function in this way implicitly assign it to some part of the class, i.e. private or protected, since it is not part of the public members?

Comment: it's private by default for `class` (and public for `struct`).

Comment: `belongs to bad programming` - no, it does not. You can assume that it's a well-known fact. It's been in C++ for decades. Every tutorial/course covers that, so everyone should know it. Even other languages have similar rules. However, a company/team/etc you are/will be working for, may have some regulated "coding style" which may simply tell you "you shall write that PRIVATE even if it's already by default" simply to keep the code uniform and easy to read for beginners. But even so, leaving it as is and relying on default well-known language feature certainly isn't a "bad programming".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, the difference between `class` and `struct` is that
for a `struct` everything is implicitly `public` and for
a `class` everything is implicitly `private`.

As soon as you use explicitly `public:`, `private:` or
`protected:` the behavior is the same in both cases
for the following members.

This is true about inheritance too.
`struct A : B` is a public inheritance.
`class A : B` is a private inheritance.

In your example, `SomeFunction()` is in the *implicit*
part of the `class`, so it is considered `private`.

A very well respected C++ expert considers this kind
of declaration (implicitly `private`) as a good practice.
( https://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html )